# iOS Twitter Sign In Memory Leaks

Tags: ios, twitter, memory-leaks

When implementing Twitter Sign In, I have noticed what I believe to be two memory leaks occurring when the keyboard is shown in the Twitter login view controller. I was just wondering if anyone had spotted this and could tell me about what is happening here. I'm fairly certain that I have implemented the log in method correctly as it is fairly straight forward (only consists of one method call) and the example code is well documented:

```
// Objective-C
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
  if (session) {
      NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
  } else {
      NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
}];
```

The two leaked objects are "_UIKeyboardTextSelectionController" and "_UIKeyboardBasedNonEditableTextSelectionGestureController".

[image]

Also I thought this detail may be useful, however I have very basic knowledge of memory management and the Leaks instrument so please excuse my inexperience. When left to run a Root Leak named "_UIKeyboardTextSelectionController" seems to accumulate over time and can be seen visually in the Cycles & Roots view of the detail pane (see image below).

[image]

Comment: I was suffering from similar problem..and i found that keyboard should be displayed on main thread, not in background...so use  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
    });
to show keyboard from main thread...I hope it'll helpful to you...